# Can I get a compile-time reference to a StaticResource in Apex?

Tags: apex, static-resources, pagereference

In Visualforce Pages, I love how we can do `{!$Page.MyPage}` or `{!$Resource.MyFileZip}` and get a hard binding to either, complete with namespace resolution and URL generation.

In Apex we can do something similar: `PageReference pr = Page.MyPage;` but not for Static Resources. The best we can do is query and hand-assemble a URL which feels a little... contrived.

```
/resource/[last_modified_time]/[namespace_prefix]__[static_resource_name]
```

Sure, we can fish it out in a single line (trying to keep it namespace agnostic too):

```
[
    SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate, NamespacePrefix, Name
    FROM StaticResource
    WHERE NamespacePrefix IN ('', 'pcb')
    AND Name = 'MyFileZip'
    ORDER BY NamespacePrefix DESC
    LIMIT 1
]
```

but then we still have to assemble the URL depending on its fully qualified name.

Is there any way to get a tighter hold on a Static Resource from within Apex code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a compile time reference to static resources (hypothesis: static resources are primarily used for assets as images, and therefore are desigedn to be of particular use in Visualforce, not Apex Code). Any such solution to dynamically (and "correctly") deferencing the static resource would depend on Visualforce. For example, one could create a DynamicComponent (Component.outputText), bind `{!$Resource.myResource}` to the `expressions.value` attribute, then read back the value, which should be correctly resolved. Or, one could use a dummy Visualforce page that supresses all headers and so on, and just outputs a single line: `{!$Resource.myResource}`. You could read this line through a REST request or `PageReference.getContent` call. Indeed, all of these alternatives feel "hokey", so I'd recommend posting an [idea on the IdeaExchange](http://ideas.salesforce.com/).

Comment: Last time I newed up an `Component.apex.outputText` I was so disappointed as it requires VF context: _System.VisualforceException: Visualforce Component types can only be created within a controller class for a Visualforce page.: External entry point_

Comment: @user320 Indeed. Visualforce is very inaccessible from non-Visualforce land. A page reference to a dummy page would work, if you were willing to waste a callout.